# maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } keep disapearing from my gradle

Tags: java, android, maven

after i installed the android studio on my new computer it keep popping me messages of errors. like so:
[image: errors of espresso-core and appcompat v7:26.+]

i found the solution to the problem and fixed it by adding the maven repository to the `build.gradle` like so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        **maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }**
    }
}
```

the problem is it keeps deleting with every project that i open, how can i add the maven permanently for all future projects?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once i update my Android Studio to the latest version at this time (3.0) and all of its SDK Tools Packages the problem went away.

Good luck.